# Trying to create a programmatic API for Reddit with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, browser, reddit

I work for a news company, and we want to be able to submit breaking news to reddit easily. I'm trying to create something that will login and post a link to reddit from just a url on our website.

Anyway, I am trying to use Javascript to click the buttons to login and I'm having problems.

Here's the button code right here:

```
<button class="btn" tabindex="4" type="submit">login</button>
```

which seems to submit this form:

```
<form class="login-form-side" onsubmit="return post_user(this, 'login');" action="http://www.reddit.com/post/login" id="login_login-main" method="post"><input type="hidden" value="login-main" name="op"><input type="text" tabindex="1" maxlength="20" name="user"><input type="password" tabindex="2" maxlength="20" name="passwd"><div style="display: none;" class="error WRONG_PASSWORD field-passwd">invalid password</div><span style="display:none" class="error RATELIMIT field-ratelimit"></span><span style="display: inline;" class="error RATELIMIT field-vdelay">you are doing that too much. try again in 1 minute.</span><div class="status error" style="display: none;"></div><div id="remember-me"><button tabindex="4" type="submit" class="btn">login</button><input type="checkbox" id="rem-login-main" tabindex="3" name="rem"><label for="rem-login-main">remember me</label><a href="/password" class="recover-password attention">recover password</a><div class="clear"></div></div></form>
```

Anyone have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Reddit has an extensively documented [API](http://www.reddit.com/dev/api) that can be accessed with POST and GET requests. Also, is there any reason you're using JS to manipulate the DOM? You could use one of the [wrappers](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/API-Wrappers) instead of manually changing the HTML DOM.